# SQL Server query to find duplicate records with join query

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server database which has tables `x`, `y` and mapping table `xy`.

Table: `x`

```
x_id             date               text
-------------------------------------------
| 1  |  2017-02-22 20:40:30.617  |    txt1   |
| 2  |  2017-02-22 20:40:06.103  |    txt1   |
| 3  |  2017-02-22 20:28:21.393  |    txt2   |
```

Table: `XY`

```
x_id   y_id 
-----------
| 1  |  3  
| 1  |  10  
| 2  |  3  
| 2  |  10
| 3  |  5
```

I have a table X with x_id, date, text and mapping table xy with x_id and y_id.
I need a query to find which records of x are duplicate. Records of x can be considered as duplicate when it satisfies all of the below conditions

1. Both has the same text
2. Date should be in the interval of 5 minutes.
3. Both should have same y_id's (in XY mapping table)

I am able to write a query to satisfy first two conditions (though with duplicate data). But I wasn't able to write a query to satisfy 3rd condition and to display distinct data when self join is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to satisfy the third criteria is to aggregate the `y_id`s into one row for comparison.

Using a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) makes this more readable for me, but it can be written without it as well.

test setup: http://rextester.com/APVZQS37775

```
create table x(
    x_id int
  , [date] datetime
  , text varchar(32)
);
insert into x values
 ( 1,'2017-02-22 20:40:30.617','txt1')
,( 2,'2017-02-22 20:40:06.103','txt1')
,( 3,'2017-02-22 20:28:21.393','txt2');

create table xy (
    x_id int
  , y_id int
);
insert into xy values 
 ( 1,3 )
,( 1,10) 
,( 2,3 )
,( 2,10)
,( 3,5 );
```

query:

```
;with cte as (
    select 
        x.*
      , y_ids = stuff((
          select ','+convert(varchar(10),xy.y_id)
          from xy
          where x.x_id = xy.x_id
          order by xy.y_id
          for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
        ,1,1,'')
    from x
)
select * 
from cte
where exists (
    select 1
    from cte as i
    where i.x_id <> cte.x_id
      and abs(datediff(minute,i.date,cte.date))<=5
      and i.text = cte.text
      and i.y_ids = cte.y_ids
)
```

results:

```
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
| x_id |        date         | text | y_ids |
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
|    1 | 2017-02-22 20:40:30 | txt1 | 3,10  |
|    2 | 2017-02-22 20:40:06 | txt1 | 3,10  |
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
```

---

A method without aggregating the `y_id`s:

```
;with cte as (
  select x.*
      , xy.y_id
      , cnt = count(*) over (partition by x.x_id)
    from x inner join xy on x.x_id = xy.x_id
)

select x.x_id, x.date, x.text
from cte as x 
  inner join cte as x2
     on x.x_id <> x2.x_id 
    and x.y_id = x2.y_id
    and x.text = x2.text 
    and x.cnt  = x2.cnt 
    and abs(datediff(minute,x.date,x2.date))<=5
group by x.x_id, x.date, x.text, x.cnt
having count(*) = x.cnt
```

returns:

```
+------+---------------------+------+
| x_id |        date         | text |
+------+---------------------+------+
|    1 | 2017-02-22 20:40:30 | txt1 |
|    2 | 2017-02-22 20:40:06 | txt1 |
+------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: Hey @Sqlzim, I tried with your solution. It seems like it is showing the records even y_ids are different.

Comment: @Raghavendra That's because I forgot to add `i.y_ids = cte.y_ids` to the `where`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It is another sample, If the x do not have relation data in XY, Does need ignore the condition 3?
This sample will ignore the condtion 3.

```
    DECLARE @x TABLE(x_id int,[date] datetime, text varchar(10))
    insert into @x values
     ( 1,'2017-02-22 20:40:30.617','txt1')
    ,( 2,'2017-02-22 20:40:06.103','txt1')
    ,( 3,'2017-02-22 20:28:21.393','txt2')
    ,( 4,'2017-02-22 20:28:21.393','txt3')
    ,( 5,'2017-02-22 20:28:21.394','txt3')
     DECLARE @xy TABLE(x_id int, y_id int)
     INSERT INTO @xy VALUES 
     ( 1,3 )
    ,( 1,10) 
    ,( 2,3 )
    ,( 2,10)
    ,( 3,5 );


    SELECT x.*,xy.* FROM @x AS x 
    INNER JOIN @x AS ox ON x.x_id!=ox.x_id AND x.text=ox.text AND ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,x.date,ox.date))<=5
    OUTER APPLY(
       SELECT COUNT(0) AS totaly, SUM(CASE WHEN xy1.y_id+xy2.y_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NULLROW
       FROM  (SELECT y_id FROM @xy WHERE x_id=x.x_id) AS xy1 FULL JOIN (SELECT y_id FROM @xy WHERE x_id=ox.x_id) AS xy2 ON xy1.y_id=xy2.y_id
    ) AS xy
    WHERE (xy.totaly>0 and xy.NULLROW=0) OR (xy.totaly=0)
```

```
x_id        date                    text       totaly      NULLROW
----------- ----------------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           2017-02-22 20:40:30.617 txt1       2           0
2           2017-02-22 20:40:06.103 txt1       2           0
4           2017-02-22 20:28:21.393 txt3       0           NULL
5           2017-02-22 20:28:21.393 txt3       0           NULL
```